# java properties file using multiple lines for one property

Tags: java, spring, properties

I am storing sql in a properties file and injecting it using spring this works :

```
someSQL = select result from myTable where y = 2 and x = ? order by z
```

but for readibility I want this :

```
    someSQL = select result 
              from myTable 
              where y = 2  
              and x = ? 
              order by z
```

What is the correct text formatting I need to use ?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Use \ at the end of the line like

```
  someSQL = select result \
              from myTable \
              where y = 2  \
              and x = ? \
              order by z
```

Also, beware of any trailing whitespaces since Java looks for consecutive backslash+linebreak when assembling the lines.

Put differently : The backslash has to be the very last caracter on the line before the line break.

Answer (score 9):

You add \ (slash) to continue on to the next line.
The properties file would be like this -

```
prop1=first line of prop1 \
second line of prop1\
third line of prop1
prop2=first line of prop2 \n \
second line of prop2 \n \
third line of prop2
```

Answer (score 9):

use **\ for new line** and make sure that there is **one space before each** \

```
   someSQL = select result \
              from myTable \
              where y = 2  \
              and x = ? \
              order by z \
```

**If One space is not given output will be like this**

```
 someSQL = select result\
              from myTable\
              where y = 2\
              and x = ?\
              order by z\
    someSQL=select resultfrom myTablewhere y = 2and x = ?order by z
```

**this will cause**

**Java level :** `java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException`

and **DB level**  `Missing Keyword`

Comment: very good add on to the other items and fixed my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's very important to tell that **after '\' MUST NOT be anything not even a single blank space** !

Comment: this should actually be a comment, not an answer