# Multi-line value in Resource.properties file?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I have a multi-line value in `Resource.properties` file:

```
TXT_ABOUT = first line \
second line \n \
third line.
```

I am displaying this in the About box:

```
<h:outputText value="#{txt.TXT_ABOUT}"/>
```

(The `txt` is defined via `faces-config.xml`:

```
<resource-bundle>
  <base-name>com.compayn.etcetc.Resources</base-name>
    <var>txt</var>
</resource-bundle>
```

but this is not important for the question.)

The problem is: new line marks in the variable definition are not shown on the rendered page, it's all in one row. Is this syntax above OK? Is `\n` OK?

Comment: add these lines to resource.propeties file..  TXT_ABOUT = first line <br/>
second line <br/>
third line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use backslash (`\`) at the end of the line. This question was already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11610789/java-properties-file-using-multiple-lines-for-one-property).

Your problem is probably because HTML doesn't care about new line. If you want to display a new line you have to use the `<br />` tag.

You can include HTML code in your properties file and the use the `escape="false"` to avoid escaping the HTML tags when generating the HTML.

```
TXT_ABOUT = first line<br />\
    second line<br />\
    third line.
```

JSF code:

```
<h:outputText value="#{txt.TXT_ABOUT}" escape="false" />
```

Comment: Thanks. One row as seen in the browser.

Comment: I inspected html with Firebug: there are no <br/>s  generated.

Comment: Do you have an idea on how to add `<br />` tags? Should I add it to xhtml file or it can be added to Resource.properties even?