# TLS version defaults to v1

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, sdk, mastercard

I am using a third party provided java SDK to make HTTP calls (SDK provides http client). When i invoke the SDK through a simple java program i see TLSv1.2 being used and calls are successful. But when i invoke the SDK through a spring-boot application (same code), the call is failing because of unsupported TLSv1 usage.

using simple java program,

```
public class SdkTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        sdk.invoke(...);
    }
}
```

using spring-boot,

```
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class MyApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class);
    }
}

@Controller
public class TestController {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public void test() {
        sdk.invoke(...);
    }
}
```

Question :

1. How is TLS version selected ?
2. Why is a different version of TLS is being selected in different programs.

Note: The SDK provides a http client to connect to a third part server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you enable TLS 1.2 on Spring-boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27989034/5221149)